# blockchain.info and blockexplorer.com show different balance for the same address

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info, blockexplorer

Does blockexplorer.com have a bug or some other reason?

https://blockexplorer.com/q/getreceivedbyaddress/1KWd23GZ4BmTMo9zcsUZXpWP4M8hmxZwRU
1.95331249

https://blockchain.info/q/getreceivedbyaddress/1KWd23GZ4BmTMo9zcsUZXpWP4M8hmxZwRU
1.90576350

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their definitions of 'total received' differ in that blockchain.info does not count change outputs as an amount 'received', whereas most other explorers do (since there is no way in general to determine if an output is really change or not, unless change is sent back to the sending address, which is the case for blockchain.info wallets).

See this [related post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/295f3o/why_do_blockchaininfo_and_insight_display/) on reddit.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, total received with change does not have much meaning with regards to balance, its like counting the same value twice.